# Deleting points which are close to each other

Tags: qgis, vector, whitebox-gat

I have a vector file containing thousands of points. Where points are within x distance from each other, I wish to delete one of the points and keep the other (either by snapping to one point, or simply erasing one of the two points)

However, in Whitebox the vector cleaning tool only works with polygons and lines.

Is there some other way I can do this with my shapefiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed Curlew's suggestion:

> have a look at this
>   tutorial:http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2013/04/tutorial-nearest-neighbor-analysis.html
>   Compute the NN for each point, join and then delete all points below a
>   threshold.

and computed the nearest neighbour analysis, joining the table to layer. Then simply exported to excel, sorted and selected by distance and then deleted duplicates via Data>delete duplicates!

**Update**: The latest tutorial is now at http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/nearest_neighbor_analysis.html

Comment: Link from flagged and now deleted comment by @Curlew has been edited in here but it is broken.

Comment: According to: https://web.archive.org/web/20190212214255/http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2013/04/tutorial-nearest-neighbor-analysis.html, the current version of the tutorial is now at http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/nearest_neighbor_analysis.html